# How do you write an ansible callback plugin to only show messages from something i explicitly write out like through debug?

Tags: ansible

Ansible stdout is very noisy. They have a set of callback plugins as described here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html
However none that come with Ansible meet what i'd like which is only to see text that i print out through an Ansible script like through debug.

I've tried to use the existing callbacks as examples but i keep getting errors. I originally tried to just pass on all the callbacks but that didn't work.

```
    from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
    __metaclass__ = type

    from ansible.plugins.callback.default import CallbackModule as 
    CallbackModule_default

    class CallbackModule(CallbackModule_default):

    '''
    This is the default callback interface, which simply prints messages
    to stdout when new callback events are received.
    '''

    CALLBACK_VERSION = 2.0
    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
    CALLBACK_NAME = 'quite'

    def __init__(self):
        super(CallbackModule, self).__init__()

    def v2_playbook_on_start(self, playbook):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_notify(self, handler, host):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_no_hosts_matched(self):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_no_hosts_remaining(self):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_task_start(self, task, is_conditional):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_cleanup_task_start(self, task):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_handler_task_start(self, task):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_vars_prompt(self, varname, private=True, prompt=None, encrypt=None, confirm=False, salt_size=None, salt=None, default=None, unsafe=None):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_import_for_host(self, result, imported_file):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_not_import_for_host(self, result, missing_file):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_stats(self, stats):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_include(self, included_file):
        pass

    #    def v2_playbook_on_play_start(self, play):
    #        pass

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    That didn't work (it was close) so i tried to modify default.py and that also didn't work:

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # (c) 2012-2014, Michael DeHaan <michael.dehaan@gmail.com>
    # (c) 2017 Ansible Project
    # GNU General Public License v3.0+ (see COPYING or 
    https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt)

    from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
    __metaclass__ = type

    DOCUMENTATION = '''
    callback: default
    type: stdout
    short_description: default Ansible screen output
    version_added: historical
    description:
        - This is the default output callback for ansible-playbook.
    extends_documentation_fragment:
      - default_callback
    requirements:
      - set as stdout in configuration
'''

from ansible import constants as C
from ansible.playbook.task_include import TaskInclude
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
from ansible.utils.color import colorize, hostcolor


# These values use ansible.constants for historical reasons, mostly to allow
# unmodified derivative plugins to work. However, newer options added to the
# plugin are not also added to ansible.constants, so authors of derivative
# callback plugins will eventually need to add a reference to the common docs
# fragment for the 'default' callback plugin

# these are used to provide backwards compat with old plugins that subclass from default
# but still don't use the new config system and/or fail to document the options
COMPAT_OPTIONS = (('display_skipped_hosts', C.DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS),
                  ('display_ok_hosts', True),
                  ('show_custom_stats', C.SHOW_CUSTOM_STATS),
                  ('display_failed_stderr', False),)


class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):

    '''
    This is the default callback interface, which simply prints messages
    to stdout when new callback events are received.
    '''

    CALLBACK_VERSION = 2.0
    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
    CALLBACK_NAME = 'quite'

    def __init__(self):

        self._play = None
        self._last_task_banner = None
        self._last_task_name = None
        self._task_type_cache = {}
        super(CallbackModule, self).__init__()

    def set_options(self, task_keys=None, var_options=None, direct=None):

        super(CallbackModule, self).set_options(task_keys=task_keys, var_options=var_options, direct=direct)

        # for backwards compat with plugins subclassing default, fallback to constants
        for option, constant in COMPAT_OPTIONS:
            try:
                value = self.get_option(option)
            except (AttributeError, KeyError):
                value = constant
            setattr(self, option, value)

    def v2_runner_on_failed(self, result, ignore_errors=False):

        delegated_vars = result._result.get('_ansible_delegated_vars', None)
        self._clean_results(result._result, result._task.action)

        if self._last_task_banner != result._task._uuid:
            self._print_task_banner(result._task)

        self._handle_exception(result._result, use_stderr=self.display_failed_stderr)
        self._handle_warnings(result._result)

        if result._task.loop and 'results' in result._result:
            self._process_items(result)

        else:
            if delegated_vars:
                self._display.display("fatal: [%s -> %s]: FAILED! => %s" % (result._host.get_name(), delegated_vars['ansible_host'],
                                                                            self._dump_results(result._result)),
                                      color=C.COLOR_ERROR, stderr=self.display_failed_stderr)
            else:
                self._display.display("fatal: [%s]: FAILED! => %s" % (result._host.get_name(), self._dump_results(result._result)),
                                      color=C.COLOR_ERROR, stderr=self.display_failed_stderr)

        if ignore_errors:
            self._display.display("...ignoring", color=C.COLOR_SKIP)

    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result):
        delegated_vars = result._result.get('_ansible_delegated_vars', None)

        if isinstance(result._task, TaskInclude):
            return
        elif result._result.get('changed', False):
            if self._last_task_banner != result._task._uuid:
                self._print_task_banner(result._task)

            if delegated_vars:
                msg = "changed: [%s -> %s]" % (result._host.get_name(), delegated_vars['ansible_host'])
            else:
                msg = "changed: [%s]" % result._host.get_name()
            color = C.COLOR_CHANGED
        else:
            if not self.display_ok_hosts:
                return

            if self._last_task_banner != result._task._uuid:
                self._print_task_banner(result._task)

            if delegated_vars:
                msg = "ok: [%s -> %s]" % (result._host.get_name(), delegated_vars['ansible_host'])
            else:
                msg = "ok: [%s]" % result._host.get_name()
            color = C.COLOR_OK

        self._handle_warnings(result._result)

        if result._task.loop and 'results' in result._result:
            self._process_items(result)
        else:
            self._clean_results(result._result, result._task.action)

            if (self._display.verbosity > 0 or '_ansible_verbose_always' in result._result) and '_ansible_verbose_override' not in result._result:
                msg += " => %s" % (self._dump_results(result._result),)
            self._display.display(msg, color=color)

    def v2_runner_on_skipped(self, result):

        if self.display_skipped_hosts:

            self._clean_results(result._result, result._task.action)

            if self._last_task_banner != result._task._uuid:
                self._print_task_banner(result._task)

            if result._task.loop and 'results' in result._result:
                self._process_items(result)
            else:
                msg = "skipping: [%s]" % result._host.get_name()
                if (self._display.verbosity > 0 or '_ansible_verbose_always' in result._result) and '_ansible_verbose_override' not in result._result:
                    msg += " => %s" % self._dump_results(result._result)
                self._display.display(msg, color=C.COLOR_SKIP)

    def v2_runner_on_unreachable(self, result):
        if self._last_task_banner != result._task._uuid:
            self._print_task_banner(result._task)

        delegated_vars = result._result.get('_ansible_delegated_vars', None)
        if delegated_vars:
            self._display.display("fatal: [%s -> %s]: UNREACHABLE! => %s" % (result._host.get_name(), delegated_vars['ansible_host'],
                                                                             self._dump_results(result._result)),
                                  color=C.COLOR_UNREACHABLE)
        else:
            self._display.display("fatal: [%s]: UNREACHABLE! => %s" % (result._host.get_name(), self._dump_results(result._result)), color=C.COLOR_UNREACHABLE)

    def v2_playbook_on_no_hosts_matched(self):
        self._display.display("skipping: no hosts matched", color=C.COLOR_SKIP)

    def v2_playbook_on_no_hosts_remaining(self):
        self._display.banner("NO MORE HOSTS LEFT")

    def v2_playbook_on_task_start(self, task, is_conditional):
        pass

    def _task_start(self, task, prefix=None):
        # Cache output prefix for task if provided
        # This is needed to properly display 'RUNNING HANDLER' and similar
        # when hiding skipped/ok task results
        if prefix is not None:
            self._task_type_cache[task._uuid] = prefix

        # Preserve task name, as all vars may not be available for templating
        # when we need it later
        if self._play.strategy == 'free':
            # Explicitly set to None for strategy 'free' to account for any cached
            # task title from a previous non-free play
            self._last_task_name = None
        else:
            self._last_task_name = task.get_name().strip()

            # Display the task banner immediately if we're not doing any filtering based on task result
            if self.display_skipped_hosts and self.display_ok_hosts:
                self._print_task_banner(task)

    def _print_task_banner(self, task):
        # args can be specified as no_log in several places: in the task or in
        # the argument spec.  We can check whether the task is no_log but the
        # argument spec can't be because that is only run on the target
        # machine and we haven't run it thereyet at this time.
        #
        # So we give people a config option to affect display of the args so
        # that they can secure this if they feel that their stdout is insecure
        # (shoulder surfing, logging stdout straight to a file, etc).
        args = ''
        if not task.no_log and C.DISPLAY_ARGS_TO_STDOUT:
            args = u', '.join(u'%s=%s' % a for a in task.args.items())
            args = u' %s' % args

        prefix = self._task_type_cache.get(task._uuid, 'TASK')

        # Use cached task name
        task_name = self._last_task_name
        if task_name is None:
            task_name = task.get_name().strip()

        self._display.banner(u"%s [%s%s]" % (prefix, task_name, args))
        if self._display.verbosity >= 2:
            path = task.get_path()
            if path:
                self._display.display(u"task path: %s" % path, color=C.COLOR_DEBUG)

        self._last_task_banner = task._uuid

    def v2_playbook_on_cleanup_task_start(self, task):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_handler_task_start(self, task):
        pass

    def v2_playbook_on_play_start(self, play):
        pass

    def v2_on_file_diff(self, result):
        if self._last_task_banner != result._task._uuid:
            self._print_task_banner(result._task)

        if result._task.loop and 'results' in result._result:
            for res in result._result['results']:
                if 'diff' in res and res['diff'] and res.get('changed', False):
                    diff = self._get_diff(res['diff'])
                    if diff:
                        self._display.display(diff)
        elif 'diff' in result._result and result._result['diff'] and result._result.get('changed', False):
            diff = self._get_diff(result._result['diff'])
            if diff:
                self._display.display(diff)

    def v2_runner_item_on_ok(self, result):
        pass

    def v2_runner_item_on_failed(self, result):
        if self._last_task_banner != result._task._uuid:
            self._print_task_banner(result._task)

        delegated_vars = result._result.get('_ansible_delegated_vars', None)
        self._clean_results(result._result, result._task.action)
        self._handle_exception(result._result)

        msg = "failed: "
        if delegated_vars:
            msg += "[%s -> %s]" % (result._host.get_name(), delegated_vars['ansible_host'])
        else:
            msg += "[%s]" % (result._host.get_name())

        self._handle_warnings(result._result)
        self._display.display(msg + " (item=%s) => %s" % (self._get_item_label(result._result), self._dump_results(result._result)), color=C.COLOR_ERROR)

    def v2_runner_item_on_skipped(self, result):
        if self.display_skipped_hosts:
            if self._last_task_banner != result._task._uuid:
                self._print_task_banner(result._task)

            self._clean_results(result._result, result._task.action)
            msg = "skipping: [%s] => (item=%s) " % (result._host.get_name(), self._get_item_label(result._result))
            if (self._display.verbosity > 0 or '_ansible_verbose_always' in result._result) and '_ansible_verbose_override' not in result._result:
                msg += " => %s" % self._dump_results(result._result)
            self._display.display(msg, color=C.COLOR_SKIP)

    def v2_playbook_on_include(self, included_file):
        msg = 'included: %s for %s' % (included_file._filename, ", ".join([h.name for h in included_file._hosts]))
        if 'item' in included_file._args:
            msg += " => (item=%s)" % (self._get_item_label(included_file._args),)
        self._display.display(msg, color=C.COLOR_SKIP)

    def v2_playbook_on_stats(self, stats):
        self._display.banner("PLAY RECAP")

        hosts = sorted(stats.processed.keys())
        for h in hosts:
            t = stats.summarize(h)

            self._display.display(u"%s : %s %s %s %s" % (
                hostcolor(h, t),
                colorize(u'ok', t['ok'], C.COLOR_OK),
                colorize(u'changed', t['changed'], C.COLOR_CHANGED),
                colorize(u'unreachable', t['unreachable'], C.COLOR_UNREACHABLE),
                colorize(u'failed', t['failures'], C.COLOR_ERROR)),
                screen_only=True
            )

            self._display.display(u"%s : %s %s %s %s" % (
                hostcolor(h, t, False),
                colorize(u'ok', t['ok'], None),
                colorize(u'changed', t['changed'], None),
                colorize(u'unreachable', t['unreachable'], None),
                colorize(u'failed', t['failures'], None)),
                log_only=True
            )

        self._display.display("", screen_only=True)

        # print custom stats if required
        if stats.custom and self.show_custom_stats:
            self._display.banner("CUSTOM STATS: ")
            # per host
            # TODO: come up with 'pretty format'
            for k in sorted(stats.custom.keys()):
                if k == '_run':
                    continue
                self._display.display('\t%s: %s' % (k, self._dump_results(stats.custom[k], indent=1).replace('\n', '')))

            # print per run custom stats
            if '_run' in stats.custom:
                self._display.display("", screen_only=True)
                self._display.display('\tRUN: %s' % self._dump_results(stats.custom['_run'], indent=1).replace('\n', ''))
            self._display.display("", screen_only=True)

    def v2_playbook_on_start(self, playbook):
        if self._display.verbosity > 1:
            from os.path import basename
            self._display.banner("PLAYBOOK: %s" % basename(playbook._file_name))

        if self._display.verbosity > 3:
            # show CLI options
            if self._options is not None:
                for option in dir(self._options):
                    if option.startswith('_') or option in ['read_file', 'ensure_value', 'read_module']:
                        continue
                    val = getattr(self._options, option)
                    if val and self._display.verbosity > 3:
                        self._display.display('%s: %s' % (option, val), color=C.COLOR_VERBOSE, screen_only=True)

    def v2_runner_retry(self, result):
        task_name = result.task_name or result._task
        msg = "FAILED - RETRYING: %s (%d retries left)." % (task_name, result._result['retries'] - result._result['attempts'])
        if (self._display.verbosity > 2 or '_ansible_verbose_always' in result._result) and '_ansible_verbose_override' not in result._result:
            msg += "Result was: %s" % self._dump_results(result._result)
        self._display.display(msg, color=C.COLOR_DEBUG)

    def v2_playbook_on_notify(self, handler, host):
        if self._display.verbosity > 1:
            self._display.display("NOTIFIED HANDLER %s for %s" % (handler.get_name(), host), color=C.COLOR_VERBOSE, screen_only=True)
```

I'd like stdout to show what i explicitly try to print through the script. Nothing about PLAY or TASK or anything that i didn't print through something like debug msg...

Comment: Have you tried using the `no_log` task option? When you set it to `True`, the output is omitted. It might be easier than developing your own callback plugin.

Comment: That unfortunately does the opposite of what i'm looking for. It gets rid of my debug messages but keeps all the play and task text: PLAY [all] *, TASK [Gathering Facts] *...